# Save the edited data in rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I show database table in a `datagridview`. I can save the records properly from `datagridview` to database in sql.

Now, I want to modify and change some records and save these changes in database. How can I do this? I'm using a binding `datasource` attached to a dataset with a `datatable`.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.cPDM0020TableAdapter.Fill(this.cpdm_dataset.CPDM0020);
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string code = dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
    string currency_Name = dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
    string boolBase = dataGridView1[2, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    string local_per_Base = dataGridView1[3, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    string base_per_Local = dataGridView1[4, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    string insert_sql = "INSERT INTO centraldb.dbo.CPDM0020(Code,Currency_Name,Base,Local_per_Base,Base_per_Local)VAL‌​UES('" + 
        code + "','" + 
        currency_Name + "','" + 
        boolBase + "','" + 
        local_per_Base + "','" + 
        base_per_Local + "')";

    if (this.ExecuteSql(insert_sql))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Insert Failed");
    }
}

public bool ExecuteSql(string command)
{

    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
    connection.Open();
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    this.cPDM0020TableAdapter.Fill(this.cpdm_dataset.CPDM0020);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = cpdm_dataset.CPDM0020;
    sqlCommand.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
    return true;
}
```

I can save the new entries easily in database and `datagridview`, but I cannot edit the already present records..On clicking save button after editing, it shows the previous value again. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Your database is not controlled by your app; it is not going to send some event back to your application when data has changed. You have to actively requery the database for changes.

The more typical approach with a DataGridView is to first apply the changes to your local copy of the data, then push the changes back to the database using a DataAdapter. This avoids refreshing the entire local dataset anytime a change is made. See Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters (ADO.NET).

The basic sequence is:

1. Connect to data source, use DataAdapter.Fill() to fill your data table
2. Define an UpdateCommand or InsertCommand that defines how data in the local DataTable will be pushed to the database
3. Add a row to your local DataTable
4. Call DataAdapter.Update() to push the updates to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you have to check if the record is exist in your table first by using Select Command

"Select * from centraldb.dbo.CPDM0020 Where Code = '" + Code + "'";

you can use this function :

```
    public bool IsExistRecord(string Query)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection);
            SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(CMD);
            DA.Fill(DT);

            if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
```

if the record exist execute update query if not exist execute insert query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code>

```
try
{
    var row = gvTransactions.CurrentRow;
    int ID= int.parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    string abc=row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
catch(exception ex)
{
}
```

Get values like this.

> Note: dont write any thing in catch block

and then fire insert/update query according to your need.

Comment: You can't declare variables in the try block, they will be lost once the try has ended.

Comment: Also, Pokémon exception handling is generally a bad idea.

Comment: This is my code:                                                  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                this.cPDM0020TableAdapter.Fill(this.cpdm_dataset.CPDM0020);}

Comment: private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            
                string code = dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
                string currency_Name = dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
                string boolBase = dataGridView1[2, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                string local_per_Base = dataGridView1[3, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

Comment: string base_per_Local = dataGridView1[4, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
string insert_sql = "INSERT INTO centraldb.dbo.CPDM0020(Code,Currency_Name,Base,Local_per_Base,Base_per_Local)VALUES('" + code + "','" + currency_Name + "','" + boolBase + "','" + local_per_Base + "','" + base_per_Local + "')";

                if (this.ExecuteSql(insert_sql))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Insert Failed");
                }

Comment: public bool ExecuteSql(string command)
        {
           
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
                connection.Open();
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                this.cPDM0020TableAdapter.Fill(this.cpdm_dataset.CPDM0020);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = cpdm_dataset.CPDM0020;
                
                sqlCommand.Dispose();
                connection.Close();
                return true;

Comment: i can save new records in the datagridview easily and they are reflected in the database also.But if i try to change any already present record,it does not update.on clicking the save button,the previous entry is again shown..

Comment: Are you sure on pressing save button you are firing update query , in case of updating present record? I think it is violeting primary key rule, thats why its not updating. Make sure about update query on pressing save button.

Comment: do you mean instead of insert query i should write update query..could you plz explain,did not get your point properly..

Comment: you said, new record gets inserted properly when you press "Save" button. But when you try to "Edit" current record in grid, and press "Save" button , its not working, hence I said: when you update current record in grid , UPDATE query should get fired which i doubt present on pressing "Save" button.

Comment: You should make another button called "Update" write code for updating record.

Comment: But i want save button itself to do both the saving and updation also..how can i do that? i have tried using update code after the insert code,bt it does not work.

Comment: do one thing, set one flag which will enable when the current row in the grid will be edited and keep it disable when you are inserting new record. And on save button, check the flag , if it is enable fire update query or if disable fire insert query.

Answer (score 0):

make an update button:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string code = dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
    string currency_Name = dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
    string boolBase = dataGridView1[2, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    string local_per_Base = dataGridView1[3, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    string base_per_Local = dataGridView1[4, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    string select_qry = "Select * from centraldb.dbo.CPDM0020 Where Code = '" + Code + "'";
   if(IsExistRecord(select_qry))
    {
    string update_qry = Update centraldb.dbo.CPDM0020 set Code,Currency_Name='" + currency_Name + "',Base='" + boolBase + "',Local_per_Base,Base_per_Local='" + base_per_Local + "' where code='" + code +"'";
    if (this.ExecuteSql(update_qry)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully.");
    } else {

        MessageBox.Show("Update Failed");
    }
    }
}
    //code taken from  Mohammad abumazen 
 public bool IsExistRecord(string Query)
 {
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection);
        SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(CMD);
        DA.Fill(DT);

        if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the [`dataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx), you could create a commands in your[`tableApdater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
Here's the article about the [`Creating a Data Access Layer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx), since you're in `winforms` you can apply that article in your project.

I hope this image will give you a hint for `save`, `update`, `edit`, `delete`.

[image]